# How to get next ques.. from array when click on next button

Tags: android, button, textview

Im new to android..

Im facing problem with next button..

I can able to display first question in textview, When i click on next button i cant able to see next question in my textview...

What im doing wrong and what im missing?

> ```
>         protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
>         pDialog.dismiss();  
>         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid));
>         JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesid, "GET", params);
>         json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
>          try {
>         int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>         if (success == 1) {
>         System.out.println("Success");
>         groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>         System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>         for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
>         JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>         String questionid = c.getString(TAG_QUESID);
>         String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
>         String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
>         System.out.println("Checking ::"+questionid);
>         id=questionid;         
>         quesid.add(questionid);
>                 class QuestionData {
>         private String questionid;
>         private String question;
>         private String answer;
>         public String getQuestionid() {
>         return questionid;
>         }
>         public void setQuestionid(String questionid) {
>               this.questionid = questionid;
>         }
>         public String getQuestion() {
>               return question;
>         }
>         public void setQuestion(String question) {
>               this.question = question;
>         }
>         public String getAnswer() {
>               return answer;
>            }
>         public void setAnswer(String answer) {
>               this.answer = answer;
>          }
>             }
>     final ArrayList < QuestionData > questionDatas = new ArrayList < QuestionData > ();
>     //questionDatas.add(questionData);      
>     if (firstQuestionParsed) {
>         TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
>             txtque.setText(question);   *// here im getting last question in the    
>                                            //textview im not gettin the first question..                         
>     }
>      QuestionData questionData = new QuestionData();
>      questionData.setQuestionid(questionid);
>      questionData.setQuestion(question);
>      questionData.setAnswer(answer);
>      questionDatas.add(questionData);
>          Button nextQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
>          nextQuestion.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>           public void onClick(View v) {
>          int counter=0;
>          if (counter < questionDatas.size()) {
>          QuestionData question = questionDatas.get(counter);
>          showNextQuestion(question);
>          TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
>          txtque.setText((CharSequence) question);  *// here i didnt get any question...
>          counter++;
>        }
>     }
>     private void showNextQuestion(
>     QuestionData question) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     }
>      });
>       }
>     } else {
>       showAlert();
>     }
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>     System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
>     }
> ```

Same time i want to display the multiple answers option in radio buttons..how to set radiobuttons and radiobutton text..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please format your code, its very messy and hard to read.

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way, like this I cannot understand a thing.

Comment: joxtraex and m0skit0- you cannot able to answer please leave it why you vote down..if you know help me and slove my problem..otherwise leave it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not writing anycode in the public void onClick(View v) {}
for OnClickListener() you should apply values in the onClick()

Comment: i changed..still i didnt get next question..see my edit code and comment in the code by hide line..

Comment: First write this class QuestionData {} out side of async task try again.you mixed all the data at one place

Comment: take in seperate class class QuestionData {private String questionid;private String question;private String answer;public String getQuestionid() {return questionid;}public void setQuestionid(String questionid) {this.questionid = questionid;     }
        public String getQuestion() {
              return question;
        }
        public void setQuestion(String question) {
              this.question = question;
        }
        public String getAnswer() {
              return answer;
           }
        public void setAnswer(String answer) {
              this.answer = answer;
         }

Comment: and button click also  i thought u wrote under postexecute() only. that one write in your main class not in async task

Comment: If i write class Questiondata outside the async task how can i call this QuestionData from onPost Execute()..

Comment: create object for that class and u can access.